# C# Deserialize Json to Model and Add Special Properties to List

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to have some sort of attribute that I can add on a model class so that during json deserialization, if a key is a certain format (in this case, ends with `_special`), it will be added to a list on the model.

ie:
C#

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> SpecialFields { get; set; }
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Height_special": "72",
    "Weight_special": "200"
}
```

So the result would be: `MyModel.Name == "John"` and `MyModel.SpecialFields` would be the key value pairs of height and weight.

Is this possible?

EDIT: Project is using .NET Core 3.1 and System.Text.Json

Comment: Yes, with a custom JSON converter: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: Also, can you provide a bit more detail as to where this will be used? It sounds like this is a web-based application or API; I can presume it's ASP.NET Core. If so, what version? Are you using JSON.NET or the new `System.Text.Json` to deserialize? Lack of these details is likely why someone just downvoted your post, and, perhaps even more importantly, why someone would have a hard time helping you - we need to do a lot of guess work... Please clarify your question with a bit more *relevant detail*. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Added those details to the question

Comment: For `System.Text.Json`, this is a better resource: https://www.thinktecture.com/en/asp-net/aspnet-core-3-0-custom-jsonconverter-for-the-new-system_text_json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a custom JSON converter for `System.Text.Json`. Here's an example that is *extensible*, and fits your specific `MyModel` class:

```cs
public class MyModelJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyModel>
{
    public override MyModel Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
                                  Type typeToConvert,
                                  JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel()
        {
            SpecialFields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        };

        string nextPropertyName = string.Empty;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonTokenType.PropertyName:
                    nextPropertyName = reader.GetString();
                    break;

                case JsonTokenType.String:
                    // Tempting to use reflection or switch here, but the if/else-if performs faster
                    if (nextPropertyName == "Name")
                    {
                        model.Name = reader.GetString();
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Make sure it's a _special field; if not, it's unrecognized!
                    int nameEndsAtIndex = nextPropertyName.IndexOf("_special");
                    if (nameEndsAtIndex == -1) throw new InvalidDataException("Unknown JSON field");

                    string key = nextPropertyName.Substring(0, nameEndsAtIndex);
                    string value = reader.GetString();

                    model.SpecialFields.Add(key, value);
                    break;
            }

        }

        return model;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer,
                               MyModel value,
                               JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName("Name");
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.Name);

        foreach (var specialField in value.SpecialFields)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName($"{specialField.Key}_special");
            writer.WriteStringValue(specialField.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() 
{ 
   Converters = { new MyModelJsonConverter() } 
};

var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(jsonString, options);
```

Note, this custom converter can *round-trip* your `MyModel` class:

```
var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<MyModel>(model, options);
```

In order to use this setup in ASP.NET Core application or Web API, you'll need to add an attribute to your model class, to let the ASP.NET Core framework know that you intend to use a custom converter:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyModelJsonConverter))]
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> SpecialFields { get; set; }
}
```

...and, just like that, the conversion will be handled *automagically*!

I strongly encourage you to step through the `Read` and `Write` methods with breakpoints, to really understand what's happening underneath. These methods will be called by the `JsonSerializer` directly; by understanding how these work, you can see how to extend this custom converter, should you have the need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with some steps:

Create a type for Json fields:

```
public class SpecialClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Height_Special { get; set; }
    public string Weight_Special { get; set; }
}
```

Convert the Json with this type:

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpecialClass>(yourJson);
```

Create dictionary of _special fields as [height as key, weight as value]:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { myObject.Height_Special, myObject.Weight_Special }
};
```

If its required to get [key, value] as [propertyName, value]:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { nameof(myObject.Height_Special), myObject.Height_Special },
    { nameof(myObject.Weight_Special), myObject.Weight_Special }
};
```

So you can get your required data in `MyModel` type as:

```
MyModel myModel = new MyModel()
{
    Name = myObject.Name,
    SpecialFields = dictionary,
};
```

Comment: That's really manual - why not use a custom converter that is *designed for this purpose*?

Comment: Also, why is your `Dictionary<int, int>`? Did you mean `Dictionary<string, string>`, as the OP indicated in their post? *Why are you mapping from width to height of the object*? The OP wanted to map from *property name* to *property value* - could you please correct your post, if you plan to keep it?

Comment: @CoolBots The point you raised is not a big deal to use int instead of string. User can understand it. Anyway I've updated answer. And if custom converter is not used, it doesn't mean this solution is wrong. Its also working. And if the solution is in classic form then not the valid reason to down-vote it.

Comment: I downvoted it because it was wrong; you fixed it, so I removed the downvote. Your "classic form" (whatever that means) approach in this case is akin to *getting into a car through the window* - it works...